# iOS - Toolbar not showing

Tags: ios, storyboard, toolbar, viewcontroller, segue

Using the storyboard I created a new screen for a second View controller and added a Toolbar at the bottom. But when the view is shown, the toolbar doesn't appear. I'm using Segue to change views.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If you're using a Navigation Controller, make sure to tick "Shows Toolbar" and add the buttons there, not on a standalone toolbar.

In order to show only on some, you'll need 2 different views, one that will hide it and another that won't and add the following to the respective view's viewWillAppear:

```
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;
```

(Set to YES to hide, NO to show)

You can play around with the Simulated Metrics on the Storyboard so as to visually simulate the run-time effect by setting Bottom Bar to either None or Toolbar instead of inferred, as appropriated.

EDIT: Check [this](http://www.sendspace.com/file/0oy5g7) sample project I made.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using a Navigation Controller, but I want to show the Toolbar only in one view. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes: you need to have a different class for that view and add the following to the viewWillAppear method:

Comment: I've edited the answer as comments are a bit more limited and can't edit them after 5 mins.

Comment: Weird: works just fine in a test project I made. I'll upload it somewhere and add the link here.

Comment: Added the sample project in the answer.

Comment: +1.. Great sample project. To sum it up, two things to remember. 1. set navController's toolbarHidden property in viewWillAppear 2. set attributes inspector -> Bottom bar to None / Toolbar as needed.

Answer (score 5):

Select the Navigation Controller in the storyboard. Under Bar Visibility, check "Shows Toolbar".

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden=NO;
```

Comment: This worked, but it shows only the Navigation Controller toolbar. Is there a way to show the view specific toolbar?

Answer (score 2):

In the show the size inspector in the field autosizinf choose to bind to the top of the screen and remove the binding to the bottom of the screen.